# Make.com Module Output Doesn't Display all the Items

Tags: make.com

I have a module that searches for Items, in the visual UI it seems like there is 20 items, but if I aggregate this module, there is actually over ~1k. Is this a limitation with Make.com? I would ideally like to know the real output from the first module.

Thanks!

I was expecting all the items to be displayed from the first module, without needing to aggregate the output.